# A formula to determine if value is part of set

Tags: kotlin

I have a set of numbers that start at 2 and increment by 60. Given any value, I want to test if the value belongs to the set. For example, these numbers belong to the set:

2, 62, 122, 182, 242, etc.

These numbers do not belong to the set:

0, 1, 3...61, 63...121,123...181 etc

I'm looking for the shortest way that this can be tested using Kotlin.

Comment: Are you just looking for `Set.contains`?

Comment: No, the set is infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something as simple as this, should work.

```
val number = 62
val isPart = number % 60 == 2
println(isPart) //will print true
```

But if you really have an actual set, you can also check if a number is part of it this way:

```
val ourSet = hashSetOf(2,62,122)//and so on
val number = 122
    
val isPart = number in ourSet
println(isPart) //will print true

//OR

val isPartSecondOption = ourSet.contains(number)
println(isPartSecondOption) //will print true
```

Comment: Thanks. Could be simplified to just: val isPart = number % 60 == 2